# How to make copy of android.media.Image object?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-image, android-image-capture

I need to make a copy of "android.media.Image" object for a solution, but since the class is defined abstract we can not make instances of it ourselves.

I am getting my instance of this object from ((ImageReader)reader).acquireLatestImage();

Is there any workaround that I can get two different clone instances of the object returned by this method?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot clone it, because you cannot create instances of it yourself.

Comment: Can I get two different Instances of "reader.acquireLatestImage()" somehow?